# Counting unique pairs of categorical variables in R

Tags: r, frequency

If I have this data:

```
One <- c(rep("X",4),rep("Y",3),rep("Z",2))
Two <- c(rep("A",2),rep("B",6),rep("C",1))

df <- data.frame(One,Two) 

  One Two
1   X   A
2   X   A
3   X   B
4   X   B
5   Y   B
6   Y   B
7   Y   B
8   Z   B
9   Z   C
```

I want to find the frequency of unique pairs (one,two). I know if I wanted to find the frequency of different elements in column `One` I would do `table(df$one)`. How about the frequency of unique pairs?

Comment: Try `table(df)`. But maybe not the output you are looking for.

Comment: @Pascal - maybe `data.frame(table(df))` then.

Comment: @thelatemail Sure. Easy and efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table(as.character(interaction(df)))
```

Or

```
library(qdap)
table(paste2(df))

# X.A X.B Y.B Z.B Z.C 
#   2   2   3   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(One,Two) %>%
      summarize(Count = n())
```

This returns a data frame like this

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: One

  One Two Count
1   X   A     2
2   X   B     2
3   Y   B     3
4   Z   B     1
5   Z   C     1
```

Comment: It should be noted this ignores possible combinations of One x Two that weren't present (as do all the other answers).

Comment: Any idea how to get a table that also includes all 0-frequency pairs?

Comment: I get this error summarize(Count = n()) Error: This function should not be called directly