# count unique row combinations in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have an original dataframe that contains a unique value in the first column, with X (no minimum or maximum) rows following that contains values pertaining to the unique value in the first column. I'm looking to find the number of unique pairs of values from columns 2-inf. for each row. The data looks like the dataframe below but on a larger scale. For example, "w" and "x" have appeared in the same row 4 times (rows 1, 3, 5, 7), "y" and "z" have appeared together in the same row twice (1, 6). I would like to count the number of unique pairs for all rows.

```
      x$`Order ID` 1    2    3    4    5
    1            1 w    x    y    z <NA>
    2            2 x    y <NA> <NA> <NA>
    3            3 u    v    w    x    y
    4            4 w <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
    5            5 w    x    y <NA> <NA>
    6            6 y    z <NA> <NA> <NA>
    7            7 t    u    v    w    x
```

I have tried to start by using setDT() from the data.table library to count the number of unique rows in general, and would then break it down to pairs of unique values within the rows, but get an error that the lengths of the rows are not equal ( because they are not). I am not well versed in R but an wondering what function can be used to do so. Thank you.

EDIT:
I also tried the count() function from the plyr library. This is on the right track, but only counts the entire unique rows, not the individual unique pairs within the rows.

```
    library(plyr)
    count(transposed[, -1])

      X1   X2   X3   X4   X5 freq
    1  t    u    v    w    x    1
    2  u    v    w    x    y    1
    3  w    x    y    z <NA>    1
    4  w    x    y <NA> <NA>    1
    5  w <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    1
    6  x    y <NA> <NA> <NA>    1
    7  y    z <NA> <NA> <NA>    1
```

EDIT 2:

Desired output from this subset of data:

```
       Pair Frequency
    1    tu         1
    2    tv         1
    3    tw         1
    4    tx         1
    5    uv         2
    6    uw         2
    7    ux         2
    8    uy         1
    9    vw         2
    10   vx         2
    11   vy         1
    12   wx         4
    13   wy         3
    14   wz         1
    15   xy         4
    16   xz         1
    17   yz         2
```

Counting the number of different 2 pair combinations in each row, and then counting the number of times those combinations appear throughout the entire dataset. Order does not matter (xy = yx).

Comment: Have you tried this [Count unique pairs of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925306/counting-unique-pairs-of-categorical-variables-in-r) or (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862105/count-unique-combinations-of-values)?

Comment: The second link you posted is on the right track, however it counts the unique rows, not just the pairs within the rows.

Comment: This is looking like a *permutation* problem, since you say that the `w`+`x` in row 1 matches `w`+`x` (different locations) within row 3. Further, it appears that your columns are ... arbitrary. Are you sure that a `data.frame` is the appropriate structure for your needs? From what you've said ... I believe it is not, I would suggest a keyed(named) `list`. So problem number 1 is that this problem will scale with permutations, so, not easy and growing complexity. If it is "always 2" (*just* pairs), then please confirm this ... but it will still grow.

Comment: I suggest that since columns are arbitrary (other than the first), an appropriate structure might be `list(id1=c('w','x','y','z'),id2=c('x','y'),id3=c('u','v','w','x','y'),...)`.

Comment: (With my "permutation" label, I'm not saying this is too hard to do, just that it is unclear to me how far this is going.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I understand what you are saying. I'm starting off with just pairs, but depending on the results of the data may want to include triplets, etc. I'm seeing this may be quite complicated - I'm relatively new to R and wasn't sure if there was a library/function that made it much simpler.

Comment: So you said that `plyr::count` is *"on the right track"*, but I don't think you've shown what your "right answer" looks like given your sample data above. It would really help to know that (since it is currently a little vague and can be interpreted in at least a few different ways).

Comment: @r2evans ok thank you. I added in what my desired output would be for this subset of data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```r
combs <- t(combn(sort(na.omit(unique(unlist(dat[,-1])))), 2))
head(combs, n=7)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "t"  "u" 
# [2,] "t"  "v" 
# [3,] "t"  "w" 
# [4,] "t"  "x" 
# [5,] "t"  "y" 
# [6,] "t"  "z" 
# [7,] "u"  "v" 
freqs <- apply(combs, 1, function(C) {
  sum(apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(a) all(C %in% a, na.rm = TRUE)))
})
combsDF <- as.data.frame(combs)
combsDF$freq <- freqs
combsDF
#    V1 V2 freq
# 1   t  u    1
# 2   t  v    1
# 3   t  w    1
# 4   t  x    1
# 5   t  y    0
# 6   t  z    0
# 7   u  v    2
# 8   u  w    2
# 9   u  x    2
# 10  u  y    1
# 11  u  z    0
# 12  v  w    2
# 13  v  x    2
# 14  v  y    1
# 15  v  z    0
# 16  w  x    4
# 17  w  y    3
# 18  w  z    1
# 19  x  y    4
# 20  x  z    1
# 21  y  z    2
```

If you only want rows with positive matches, then

```r
combsDF[ combsDF$freq > 0, ]
#    V1 V2 freq
# 1   t  u    1
# 2   t  v    1
# 3   t  w    1
# 4   t  x    1
# 7   u  v    2
# 8   u  w    2
# 9   u  x    2
# 10  u  y    1
# 12  v  w    2
# 13  v  x    2
# 14  v  y    1
# 16  w  x    4
# 17  w  y    3
# 18  w  z    1
# 19  x  y    4
# 20  x  z    1
# 21  y  z    2
```

This could likely easily be extended to include more than just "2" combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work for you.

```
library(dplyr)
# Go through each row and count combo occurrences
data.df$counts <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data.df)){
  values <- unlist(data.df[i,-c(1, nrow(data.df))]) %>% 
    as.character() %>% 
    subset(!(. %in% "<NA>")) %>%
    unique()
  # if there are enough unique values to make at least one combo, count it:
  if(length(values) > 1) {
    values <- combn(x = values, m = 2)
    data.df$counts[i] <- sapply(
      X = 1:ncol(values), 
      FUN = function(x){paste(as.character(values[,x]), collapse = "")}
    ) %>% length
  } else {
    data.df$counts[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

**EDIT** I see you want a tally for each pair instead:

```
# Make data.frame of all possible unique combos
combos <- unlist(data.df[,-1]) %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  subset(!(. %in% c("<NA>", ""))) %>%
  unique() %>%
  as.data.frame(x = combn(x = ., m = 2))
combos.df <- data.frame(
  combo = sapply(
    X = 1:ncol(combos), 
    FUN = function(x){paste(as.character(combos[,x]), collapse = "")}), 
  freq = 0)

# Go through each row and count combo occurences
for (i in 1:nrow(data.df)){
  values <- unlist(data.df[i,-c(1, nrow(data.df))]) %>% 
    as.character() %>% 
    subset(!(. %in% "<NA>")) %>%
    unique()
  # if there are enough unique values to make at least one combo, count it:
  if(length(values) > 1) {
    values <- combn(x = values, m = 2)
    values <- sapply(
      X = 1:ncol(values), 
      FUN = function(x){paste(as.character(values[,x]), collapse = "")})
    for(j in 1:nrow(combos.df)){
      if(combos.df$combo[j] %in% values){
        combos.df$freq[j] <- as.numeric(as.character(combos.df$freq[j])) + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
> combos.df
   combo freq
1     wx    4
2     wu    0
3     wy    3
4     wt    0
5     wv    0
6     wz    1
7     xu    0
8     xy    4
9     xt    0
10    xv    0
11    xz    1
12    uy    1
13    ut    0
14    uv    2
15    uz    0
16    yt    0
17    yv    0
18    yz    2
19    tv    1
20    tz    0
21    vz    0
```